# OSX 10.13.6 KernelRestarter: restarting kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I’ve installed Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64 on OSX 10.13.6, launched Jupyter 6.0.3 from the Anaconda navigator interface, accessed to the web page.
When I type import pandas as pd, the kernel fails, here is the log in the jupyter_mac command

```
Last login: Sun Apr 12 18:17:37 on ttys000
(base) iMac:~ laurent$ /Users/laurent/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
[I 18:40:26.241 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/laurent/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:40:26.242 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/laurent/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 18:40:26.797 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/laurent
[I 18:40:26.797 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:40:26.797 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=0d0e5fb4379863a9309b95e8f76551438482efe985584d1d
[I 18:40:26.797 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=0d0e5fb4379863a9309b95e8f76551438482efe985584d1d
[I 18:40:26.797 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:40:26.833 NotebookApp] 
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/laurent/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-19479-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=0d0e5fb4379863a9309b95e8f76551438482efe985584d1d
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=0d0e5fb4379863a9309b95e8f76551438482efe985584d1d
[I 18:41:35.208 NotebookApp] Kernel started: e727a8dc-4fba-4dc5-b922-a27399dcb8e6
[I 18:41:44.206 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel e727a8dc-4fba-4dc5-b922-a27399dcb8e6 restarted
[I 18:42:06.415 NotebookApp] Saving file at /dev/python/MLPython/First step.ipynb
[I 18:42:11.228 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel e727a8dc-4fba-4dc5-b922-a27399dcb8e6 restarted
[I 18:43:34.848 NotebookApp] Saving file at /dev/python/MLPython/First step.ipynb
```

I’ve checked in ~/opt/anaconda3/bin

```
./jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/laurent/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

There is no other error, it just crash